# Is よう used for first person or second person imperatives?

Tags: grammar

The volitional form is often translated as "let's," but that's a first person plural imperative and I am not sure if that's the case for Japanese. In Japanese dictionaries, one of the definitions for the volitional form is:

> 勧誘や婉曲な命令を表す。下に「か」「じゃないか」などが付いて，意味を強めることがある。 「いっしょにジョギングでもしよう」 「少しおなかがすいてきた。すしでも食べようか」

At first glance, it seems that it's a second person imperative such as in expressions like 私と行こうよ. It would seem strange to order yourself to go somewhere with yourself. However, it being a second person imperative doesn't seem to work with other sentences such as みんなで行こうよ and 全員で行こうよ where "I" seems to be included with みんな and 全員. This leaves me at a loss as to who the 勧誘や婉曲な命令 is directed to when the subject is omitted and it's just a verb. For example, if a group of people were about to go somewhere and someone said 行こう, is it a second person imperative with 私と omitted or a first person plural imperative?

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15889/can-the-volitional-form-be-used-when-the-speaker-is-not-intending-to-do-the-acti?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used for both, but the use as second person imperatives is a "hack". E.g. one can say `ドア閉めようぜ` to a person, and it's clear that the other person closes the door alone. Yet literary it would mean `Let's close the door (together)`. Similarly, one can say `そういうこと言うのやめようよ` and it's clear the speaker isn't doing that activity, but it doesn't quite mean `Don't say such things`, it's more like `Let us (as society) not say such things`.

Same with `私と行こうよ`, `私と` is just elaborating on the activity suggested. If you say `たかしと行こうよ` it's implied that the speaker comes as well, unless it's used in the hacky way e.g.

> 「上の子がかわいそうじゃん、下の子と動物園とか連れて行こうよ」
>   The older child would be sad. Let's (as a society) take both children to the zoo etc.

In the above example it can be that the speaker won't come. This hack is used to avoid being rude/inconsiderate.